# How to store 4, 2 by 2 arrays into a larger 4 by 4 one?

Tags: multidimensional-array, c#-4.0

I have a list of 4 2-by-2 arrays. I want them to be stored together in a larger 4-by-4 array. The first 2 arrays compose of the "first row", the last 2 arrays compose the "second row".

**Code**

```
static void Test(){
            int[,] arr1 = {
                {0,1},
                {2,3}
            };
            int[,] arr2 = {
                {4,5},
                {6,7}
            };
            int[,] arr3 = {
                {8,9},
                {10,11}
            };
            int[,] arr4 = {
                {12,13},
                {14,15}
            };

            List<int[,]> arrList = new List<int[,]>();
            int[,] result = new int[4,4];
            arrList.Add(arr1);
            arrList.Add(arr2);
            arrList.Add(arr3);
            arrList.Add(arr4);

            int v = 0;

            foreach(int[,] x in arrList){
                for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                        result[v*i-1,v*j-1] = x[i,j];      //This needs to change
                    }
                }
                v += 1;
            }
        }
```

The end goal based on this example should be

```
0 1 4 5
2 3 6 7
8 9 12 13
10 11 14 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used the following function. What this function does is it loops over  2 by 2 or 3 by 3 arrays, and combines them to a larger n by n array.

```
private static string[,] Combine(List<string[,]> arrList){

            int elements = arrList.Count * arrList[0].Length;
            int n = (int) Math.Pow((double) elements, 0.5);

            string[,] result = new string[n,n];       

            int k = 0;
            int r = 0;

            int by = 0;
            int amt = 0;

            if(arrList[0].Length % 2 == 0){
                by = (int) Math.Pow(arrList[0].Length, 0.5);
                amt = n/by;

            }else if(arrList[0].Length % 3 == 0){
                by = (int) Math.Pow(arrList[0].Length, 0.5);
                amt = n/by;
            }

            for(int v = 0; v < arrList.Count; v++){

                if(v%amt == 0 && v != 0){
                    k=0;
                    r +=1;
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < by; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < by; j++){
                        result[r*by+i, k*by+j] = arrList[v][i,j];    
                    }
                }                
                k+=1;
            }
            return result;
        }
```